# Instruction pointer to function name, input parameters, ?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, gdb, bfd

I am trying to implement backtrace like function call myself . I have been successfully able to unroll stack and i have all return address present on my stack . Now i want to get function name, variable name input to my function from this information. Also i want to do this programmatically i.e at run time i should be able to get info about all the functions that have been called till now in my program. 
Lets assume i am fine compiling my with -g flag while compiling.

I am trying to use dladdr() function to get function name, but this did not work . It gives me error that "error: unknown type name ‘Dl_info’" . 
Here is my code snippet :

```
const char * get_func_name(void *ip){
        Dl_info info;
        int ret;
        ret = dladdr(ip,&info);
        if(ret < 0)
                return NULL;
        return info.dli_fname;
}
```

I tried researching bfd library , but didnt  have good example/tutorial , any help ? 
I am using ubunutu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

Per the man page, be sure to `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before you `#include <dlfcn.h>`.  This structure, and `dladdr()`, are GNU extensions.